# SharePoint Hosted Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have few confusions related to SharePoint hosted apps.

1. Difference between hostweb and appweb?
2. Where do we store the list that we want to be accessed by the app? (Hostweb or the appweb)
3. If we can keep list in appweb then how do we create it in appweb?
4. What different we need to do in code when we access list in appweb from hostweb?
5. what is the scope of app created?
6. What is the purpose of adding it to app catalog?

Comment: too many questions in a single post!!! it also seems you have not search anything in the web.

Comment: I have searched for it but not getting clear idea so i asked all these here.